# How to append last item to the array in swift3?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, xcode8

I am using two arrays namely dateArray and combinedArray . The values of dateArray is appended to the comBinedArray. For this i am using the following code:

```
var dataArray = [Any]()
print(self.yourArray)
if let threeDayForecast = end.travelShopsData {
    for forecast in threeDayForecast {
        var index: Int = (threeDayForecast as NSArray).index(of: forecast)
        if self.dateArray.count != 0 {
            self.combinedArray.append(self.dateArray)
            print("combinedArray: \(self.combinedArray)")
            print("combinedArray count: \(self.combinedArray.count)")
        }
        self.dateArray.removeAll()
        self.nameArray.append(forecast.name as Any)
        self.addressArray.append(forecast.address as Any)
        dataArray.append(forecast.cashPointOperatingDays as Any)
        print(forecast.name as Any)
        print(forecast.address as Any)
        print(forecast.phoneNumber as Any)
        print(forecast.latitude as Any)
        print(forecast.longitude as Any)
        print(forecast.cashPointOperatingDays as Any)
        for var i in 0...forecast.cashPointOperatingDays.count/2 {
            var cashPointArray = forecast.cashPointOperatingDays[i ] as? [String: String]
            let retrieveArray = cashPointArray?["operatingDay"]
            self.dateArray.append(retrieveArray)
            print(i)
            print("Data Array: \(self.dateArray)")
            var joiner = ":"
            let str = self.dateArray.flatMap { $0 as? String }.joined()
            print("joinedStrings: \(str)")
        }
    }
}
```

But the problem is that dateArray is having 7 elements which is true in it but after appending to the combinedArray . The combinedArray only contains 6 elements. What is wrong with the above code?

Comment: `dateArray`!= `dataArray`, one has an "e" in it.

Comment: Sorry i meant dateArray

Comment: `self.combinedArray.append(self.dateArray)` looks absolutely fine - and `self.combinedArray` isn't touched anywhere else in your code so this should be working fine. You are only printing out the count of `combinedArray` - how do you know that `dateArray` has 7 elements in?

Comment: @deanWombourne I fixed it dear.. Happy to hear from you